# Using a function to include files, not recognizing global variables

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to my database using a function I've used in a previous project. The only thing I've changed is, I've added a loader.php file.

**loader.php**

I've made this loader to include my files, starting from the root path, because I was getting some issues with relative pathing when working with multiple pages in different directories.

```
<?php 

function includeFile($path) {
    include ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/'.$path);
}

function requireFile($path) {
    require ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/'.$path);   
}

function includeFileOnce($path) {
    include_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/'.$path);   
}

?>
```

**include/backend/db_config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * database login details
 */
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "****"); 
define("PASSWORD", "****");
define("DATABASE", "****");

define("SECURE", FALSE); //development purposes
?>
```

**include/backend/db_connect.php**

```
<?php
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '\db_config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
?>
```

**include/backend/url_translator.php**

```
<?php
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '\db_connect.php';

function getUrl($mysqli) {
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT english, dutch FROM url_translation")) { //line 5
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmt->bind_result($english, $dutch);
        $stmt->fetch();

        echo $english . "<br>";
        echo $dutch . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**examplePage.php**
When just using include() everything works and I'm getting results from the query. But when I'm using includeFile(); I'm getting 2 errors that I've listed below.

```
<?php
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/loader.php' );
//include('../backend/url_translator.php'); //works
includeFile('backend/url_translator.php'); //function from loader.php doesn't work
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            getAllUrl($mysqli); //line 12
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**error when visiting examplePage**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\en\examplePage.php on line 12

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\include\backend\url_translator.php on line 5
```

It is possible to fix the first error by adding global $mysqli; at url_translator.php. But I've passed $mysqli through a parameter.

Why does it react differently when using a function to include files instead of just using include()?

All I can think about that it might be a scoping problem, but I have not a clue on how to fix it.

Comment: why using a function when you only need to have the "global" string inside one var like $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/'; and do normal include like : include($root.'backend/model/url_translator.php'); ?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. That is a way to fix this problem :) but I'm still interested in knowing why it doesn't work when using the loader.php function. Do you have any idea on why? Thanks again Marco!

Comment: It doesn't work because of the scope i think, you are inside a function after all, you need to globalize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you echo the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/' . $path` when you call `includeFile()` in examplePage.php?

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/include/backend/url_translator.php

Comment: So it's missing the 'model' part of the file name? If I were you and I'm wrapping the include function, I might as well do a file_exists() check beforehand just to be sure too.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've edited the path by removing model because I thought I also removed them on the main question to avoid some confusion. 
But I've just tried what you've mentioned and it fixed the second error :) I just had to add the global $mysqli to remove all the errors. Thanks user900030 :D But do you know why it doesn't work when I don't wrap it in the function?

Comment: You are welcome :) Unfortunately I don't have a short answer for your question. PHP does weird things when it comes to file inclusion, that much I know. You will need to step into the code to figure it out.